# How do I change a class that is above the element that contains a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements here:

```
<div class="class1">Number 1</div>
<div class="class1">EQRST923</div>
```

However, there are multiple classes on the page like that. How do I change it so if class1 contains EQRST923, Number 1's text gets changed to Working?

I would like to use jQuery, but generic JavaScript would also be acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: "I would like to use jquery, but javascript would be good to include as well." I know what you mean, but this sounds silly.

Comment: I added solution but I'm not sure that previous element must contain `Number 1`. Should it contain this text or in previous div can be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".class1:contains('EQRST923')").prev().text('Working');
```

**EDIT:**

as `pXl` said, `:contains` its not exact. So i found solution

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tM6tJ/)

You can extend jQuery expression like this:

```
$.extend( $.expr[":"], {
    containsExact: $.expr.createPseudo ?
    $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
        return function(elem) {
            return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === text;
        };
    }) :
    // support: jQuery <1.8
    function(elem, i, match) {
        return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === match[3];
    }
});
```

And then simply use as previous one, but using `:containsExact`:

```
$(".class1:containsExact('EQRST923')").prev().text('Working');
```

My solution is edited code i founded on [jQuery Selectors - Adding a :contains exact match](http://wowmotty.blogspot.sk/2010/05/jquery-selectors-adding-contains-exact.html).

Comment: @pXL - true :/ If there will not be that duplicities its usable

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.class1').each(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).text()) === "EQRST923"){
     $(this).prev('.class1').text('Working');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
$('.class1').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() === "EQRST923" && $(this).prev().text() === "Number 1")
       $(this).prev().text("Working");
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fzyhd/)**

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function that you can add to your file :

```
//@Author Karl-André Gagnon
if(!$.fn.filterText) $.fn.filterText = function(text, caseSensitive){
    var returnedObj = $(),
        caseSensitive = caseSensitive || false,
        $this = $(this);
    if(text instanceof Array){
        for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            if(typeof text[i] == 'string'){
                returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
                    var search = caseSensitive ? text[i] : new RegExp(text[i], 'i')
                    return $(this).text().search(search) != -1;
                }))
            }else if(text[i] instanceof RegExp){
                returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
                    return $(this).text().search(text[i]) != -1;
                }))
            }
        }
    }else if(typeof text == 'string'){
        returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
            var search = caseSensitive ? text : new RegExp(text, 'i')
            return $(this).text().search(search) != -1;
        }))
    }else if(text instanceof RegExp){
        returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
            return $(this).text().search(text) != -1;
        }))
    }
    return returnedObj;
}
```

The you can call it like that :

```
$('.class1').filterText('EQRST923').prev().text('Working');
```

This function do many more thing, but for your case, it is doing the same as :

```
$(".class1:contains('EQRST923')").prev().text('Working');
```

**Edit:** Saw this comment :

*this will work even if text is EQRST923222222* -pXL

So change it for that :

```
$('.class1').filterText(/^EQRST923$/).prev().text('Working');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZNPP7/

If you think this is too much code (and just need the regex), you can reduce the method to that:

```
if(!$.fn.filterText) $.fn.filterText = function(text){
    var returnedObj = $();
    if(text instanceof RegExp){
        returnedObj = returnedObj.add($this.filter(function(){
            return $(this).text().search(text) != -1;
        }))
    }
    return returnedObj;
}
```

Comment: This long method is like calling police when your brother hit you :)

Comment: Well, first i don't think it is a "long method" and 2 it is pretty usefull when you have more than 1 input to do. Anyway, just copied it from my files and shared it.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on nothing except the fact that they are next to each other is very fragile, and your code will break if someone decides to change the layout and moves them into separate table cells, for example.

Instead, either add a wrapping div:

```
<div class="class1group">
  <div class="class1label">Number 1</div>
  <div class="class1">EQRST923</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.class1').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).text()) === "EQRST923"){
        $(this).parent('.class1group').find('.class1label').first().text('Working');
    }
});
</script>
```

Or just use data-attributes (bonus: you get to use css selectors for speed :):

```
<div class="class1" data-label-for="EQRST923">Number 1</div>
<div class="class1">EQRST923</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.class1[data-label-for="EQRST923"]').text('Working');
</script>
```